# Can installing a modem help with the GPS of Samsung Captivate?

Tags: custom-roms, gps, samsung-captivate

Like most Samsung Captivate users, I find the GPS hardware in my phone to be unsatisfactory. I have the impression that the actual GPS signal is pretty much useless and the phone (Samsung Captivate) gets location via wifi signals only.

I heard that you can flash modems to improve the GPS. They are often posted on xda-developers without much information for newbies, like [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1227717). Since I've never done it before, I thought I would ask for some information. Can I just choose a modem and install it on top of the custom ROM that I'm using? Or do I have to get a ROM that has the correct modem inside?

[This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2057574) is the rom that I'm currently using which works fine for my device.

Comment: I think you are misled about what [modems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem) are (by a wide margin). If I am correct, modems are hardware component and cannot be installed as you describe. Moreover, modems and GPS are two different **unrelated hardware** components. By the way, did you use any spell checker or translator to compose this query? ;)

Comment: Well, you obviously have not seen the usage of the word "modem" in the context that I am talking about. Please take a look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1227717) to see that the hardware component is not the only meaning that the word is being used in this context.

I'm curious, why did you ask about spell checkers or translators?

Comment: Some thing new for me to learn! I am not a native English speaker. I assumed that the word modem was a replacement suggested by a spell checker or translator software. Being a non native English speaker I had fell into many such pitfalls. No other intention other than this. :)